# "BOOL highlighted" property in UIView rather than UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

While I was reading Apple's [`TableViewSuite sample code`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318), I found something a bit confusing:

The `APLTimeZoneView` is a UIView in the `contentView` of `APLTimeZoneCell`. However, there is a property named

```
@property (nonatomic, getter=isHighlighted) BOOL highlighted
```

in the `APLTimeZoneView`, and obviously the custom setter of the property is getting called when ever a row is selected.

My question is, why is the highlighted property in the `APLTimeZoneView` instead of the `APLTimeZoneCell` ? I checked the API docs and it seems that there is no such property in `UIView`, only in `UITableViewCell`. And why is the setter getting called to set `highlighted` to true whenever a row is selected ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html), there is a very small note that says:

> The content is selected automatically if the subview implements (if appropriate) the accessor methods for the [highlighted](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/highlighted) property.

**Note**: To achieve the same thing in Swift, you would need to provide a computed property so you can annotate both `set` and `get` with specific `@objc` names:

```
private var _highlighted: Bool = false
var highlighted: Bool {
    @objc(isHighlighted) get { return _highlighted }
    @objc(setHighlighted:) set {
        _highlighted = newValue

        // Now configure the view based on the new value...
    }
}
```